# Troubles with Calculator

Tags: java, calculator

I am working on a VERY simple calculator with Java and it does not seem to output an answer after selecting the operation. The code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calc {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    Double fnum;
    Double snum; 
    Double answer;
    String operation; 
    System.out.println("Enter a number.");
    fnum = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter another number.");
    snum = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("What operation do you wish for? [Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction, Division]");
    operation = keyboard.next(); 
    if (operation == "Multiplication" || operation == "multiplication" || operation == "*") { 
        answer = fnum * snum;
        System.out.print("Your answer is: " + answer);

    }   
    else if (operation == "Division" || operation == "division" || operation == "/") { 
        answer = fnum / snum;
        System.out.print("Your answer is: " + answer);

    }   
    else if (operation == "Addition" || operation == "addition" || operation == "+" || operation == "add") { 
        answer = fnum + snum;
        System.out.print("Your answer is: " + answer);

    }   
    else if (operation == "Subtraction" || operation == "subraction" || operation == "-" || operation == "subtract"){ 
        answer = fnum - snum;
        System.out.print("Your answer is: " + answer);

    }
      else {
        System.out.println("This is not valid.");
    }


}

}
```

and this is the output:

```
Enter a number.
6
Enter another number.
6
What operation do you wish for? [Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction, Division]
Multiplication 
This is not valid.
```

Any help would be very appreciated. 
P.S. there are no errors. 
Thanks!

Comment: Darth, replace things like `operation == "Multiplication"` with `operation.compareTo("Multiplication")==0` and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems. A problem with Scanner and with the condition

`keyboard.nextDouble()`, `keyboard.next()` etc... (all except `.nextLine()` ) leave the newline ( `\n` or `Enter` ) in the buffer. This can cause problems etc..

I suggest adding a delimiter using `keyboard.useDelimiter("\n");`. This only needs to be done once and can be done right after initialization of `keyboard`.

That way, it will only see the `Enter` as a signal to end that current input.

Also, the conditions must all be using the `.equals()` method or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` which is written as:

```
operation.equals("Multiplication");
```

or

```
operation.equalsIgnoreCase("multiplication");
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings should be compared via .eqauals() method. So put in the if clause operation.equals("Multiplication")...and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings by reference, not by their values. Use `.equals()` instead!

Answer (score 0):

As @Sebastian said you should use equals instead of ==
You can improve it a little bit to avoid the spaces mistakes or case (upper case or lower case) issues by doing it the following way:

```
if (operation.trim().toUpperCase().equals("MULTIPLICATION") || operation.trim().equals("*"))
```

That way it will work for Multiplication multiplication but also MulTIpliCation, etc.

You can get the same result using equalsIgnoreCase also